# MySQL ORDER BY last n characters of a column value

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a FIELD called CUSTOMERID in my Database which has values that look like this:

**SFFG2443**

The last four characters are always a four digit number which counts up, the first four characters are some random letters means it looks like that:

**SFFG2443

FGTG2444

XDGG2445

...**

I simply want to sort my table by only taking the LAST four digits(2443,2444,2445) into account. Is that possible with a single SQL-Statement?

Comment: Add ORDER BY substr(customerid,4,4); to your query

Comment: don't run it thru `explain` btw :>

Comment: as part of The Stack community we would generally highly recommend you don't save data like this if you have much of it and performance matters. You will learn that over time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice, i am actually in the middle of rearranging the database. I did not start it like that, i took over a year old project. I do not like it like this either ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable
ORDER BY RIGHT(CUSTOMERID,4)
```

Should do the trick!

Answer (score -1):

The Comment from Nobert van Nobelen works perfectly. The whole query looks like this:

```
SELECT customerid FROM customers ORDER BY substr(customerid,4,8) DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

Here is a link to the documentary for [substr()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx).